# How to add multiple directories in ./configure --libdir?

Tags: makefile, configure

In a Makefile, there is the following:

```
 ./configure  --prefix=$(ROOTPATH) --libdir=$(MJSONLIBDIR)
```

How can I include multiple directories in --libdir?

Comment: Note that the `--libdir` option for `configure` tells it where to install libraries so specifying it multiple times seems an odd thing to do.  Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to include more than on directory in libdir

Comment: Again, what do you want to achieve by designating multiple `libdir`s?  The request suggests that you have the wrong idea about what `--libdir` does.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I' m mistaken in the option --libdir. It is not the dir to include for link by .configure process, but the dir to install the libraries created.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be closed. I confuse the role of --libdir, it is to install the libraries generated in the `$./configure && make` process, not the libraries to include for the proper execution of `$./configure && make` command.